# How can I make a nested master page razor section not defined?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, master-pages

In Razor, I have a master page with a section defined in it with code that shows some default if there is no value:

```
<html>
<head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("optionalSection"))
    {
        @RenderSection("optionalSection", required: false)
    }
    else
    {
        <div>Some default content</div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a nested master page on top of this which creates a pass through section definition:

```
@section optionalSection {
    @RenderSection("optionalSection", required: false)
}
```

The problem I am running into is that when I use this nested master page, the master page thinks the section is always defined.  This will never display the else part.  I thought about changing the name of the section in the nested master and checking for that in the master, but we have a number of nested masters and I felt like there would be an unnecessary explosion in the master if we follow that pattern.  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom extension method:

```
public static class SectionExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult RedefineSection(
        this WebPageBase page,
        string sectionName
    )
    {
        if (page.IsSectionDefined(sectionName))
        {
            page.DefineSection(
                sectionName,
                () => page.Write(page.RenderSection(sectionName))
            );
        }
        return new HelperResult(_ => { });
    }
}
```

and then inside your Nested layout call this extension method to redefine the section:

```
@this.RedefineSection("optionalSection")
```